# Maximum sum subarray in 2D in O(mn min(m,n) log max(m,n)) using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, divide-and-conquer, arrays, kadanes-algorithm

The question is:

given a 2D array [1:m,1:n], we have to find a max sum subarray [a:b,c:d] where 1<=a<=b<=m and 1<=c<=d<=n such that the sum of the elements of the array are (Summation)A[i,j] where a<=i<=b and c<=j<=d in time complexity O(mn min(m,n) log max(m,n))

I would like to know how to solve the problem.I was thinking in the following-

1)I will use Kadane's algorithm on each row to find the cumulative sum of each element from the middle  towards the right and left of the 2x2 matrix

2)Sort the sums on the right hand side based on increasing order

3)Map each element on the left handside to the max element on the right hand side and choose the row which has the maximum value..

4)Repeat the procedure from the middle towards the top and bottom of the 2x2 matrix also(cumulative sum)

5)Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the same

6)Combine max value obtained by both methods and use that as the max sum subarray

Comment: so what is your exact question?

Comment: What's the definition for "2D"? A 2D array and the subarray also rectangular? Or the subarray is simply a connected component? I don't think direct apply of Kadane's algorithm a sound and good start.

Comment: Does it have to be divide and conquer?

Comment: Yes it has to be done using divide and conquer.The question is given a 2D array [1:m,1:n], we have to find a max sum subarray [a:b,c:d] where 1<=a<=b<=m and 1<=c<=d<=n such that the sum of the elements of the array are (Summation)A[i,j] where a<=i<=b and c<=j<=d in time complexity O(mn min(m,n) log max(m,n))